# presto + hive: CLUSTERED TABLE

Tags: linux, hadoop, hive, presto

I have Clustered Table in HIVE.

All queries works in hive-client.

But in presto I can't run any query with this table:

```
     Query ... failed: Hive table is corrupt. 
     It is declared as being bucketed, but the files do not match the 
     bucketing declaration. 
     The number of files in the directory (0) does not match the declared 
     bucket count (8) for partition: <UNPARTITIONED>
```

After  `set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;`

Error:

```
Query ... failed: Hive table is corrupt. 
It is declared as being bucketed, but the files do not match the bucketing declaration. 
Found sub-directory in bucket directory for partition: <UNPARTITIONED>
```

Need help.

Answer (score 2):

`set hive.enforce.bucketing = true` makes sure the data you insert is put in the right bucket. It seems like a *previously* inserted data causes this corruption.

You should remove it and insert again, setting `hive.enforce.bucketing` to `true` beforehand.